# How to diagnose problems (Failed to route and batch data on XXX channel)?

Tags: database, database-replication, symmetricds

I am using SymmetricDS and i have stumbled across a problem on one of my clients.

Log says:

2015-11-11 09:10:57,688 ERROR [blagajna_XXX] [RouterService] [blagajna_XXX-job-17] Failed to route and batch data on 'cFpromet' channel
java.lang.NullPointerException

There is no further explanation for null pointer exception, so i can't debug it myself. Replication itself works for some time and then this error appears and replication stops working. Identical system works without any problems.

select * from sym_outgoing_batch where error_flag=1; returns 0 rows, so how can i debug this problem?

GregaJ

EDIT:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jumpmind.db.platform.AbstractJdbcDdlReader.getTableNamePattern(AbstractJdbcDdlReader.java:638)
    at org.jumpmind.db.platform.AbstractJdbcDdlReader$3.execute(AbstractJdbcDdlReader.java:574)
    at org.jumpmind.db.platform.AbstractJdbcDdlReader$3.execute(AbstractJdbcDdlReader.java:563)
    at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate.execute(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:432)
    at org.jumpmind.db.platform.AbstractJdbcDdlReader.readTable(AbstractJdbcDdlReader.java:563)
    at org.jumpmind.db.platform.AbstractDatabasePlatform.readTableFromDatabase(AbstractDatabasePlatform.java:239)
    at org.jumpmind.db.platform.AbstractDatabasePlatform.getTableFromCache(AbstractDatabasePlatform.java:314)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.AbstractSymmetricDialect.getTable(AbstractSymmetricDialect.java:377)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.RouterService.routeData(RouterService.java:689)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.RouterService.selectDataAndRoute(RouterService.java:634)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.RouterService.routeDataForChannel(RouterService.java:436)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.RouterService.routeDataForEachChannel(RouterService.java:328)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.RouterService.routeData(RouterService.java:175)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.job.RouterJob.doJob(RouterJob.java:40)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.job.AbstractJob.invoke(AbstractJob.java:180)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:224)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What's the logging level? Try lowering it to DEBUG or TRACE to see if there'll be something more useful in the logs

Comment: @BorisPavlović I am contacting server admin, so for now this is in progress, will update when i get some info back. Thank you for your input.